# POSTGRE how to select parent name from hierarchical table

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

How to select hierarchical table with parent id? 
I have a table like this

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+
| id        | parent_id  | name        |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|1          | 0          | a           |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|2          | 1          | a1          |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|3          | 0          | b           |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|4          | 3          | b1          |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|5          | 3          | b2          |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

and I want to show the table like this

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+
| id        | name       | parent      |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|1          | a          | NULL        |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|2          | a1         | a           |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|3          | b          | NULL        |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|4          | b1         | b           |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|5          | b2         | b           |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

Is it possible to create select like this? Anyone know how to create this in Postgre or MySQL, please give me some suggest,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a `left join`:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.name as parent
from yourtable t1
left join yourtable t2
on t1.parent_id = t2.id
order by t1.id
```

[<kbd>Demo Here</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ba2f7/2)

Comment: I just have one table

Comment: Yes, `self join`, isn't it? @yuliantosaparudin